# Calculate floor(pow(2,n)/10) mod 10 - sum of digits of pow(2,n)

Tags: c++, math, modular-arithmetic

This is also a math related question, but I'd like to implement it in C++...so, I have a number in the form `2^n`, and I have to calculate the sum of its digits ( in base 10;P ). My idea is to calculate it with the following formula:

```
sum = (2^n mod 10) + (floor(2^n/10) mod 10) + (floor(2^n/100) mod 10) + ...
```

for all of its digits: `floor(n/floor(log2(10)))`.

The first term is easy to calculate with modular exponentiation, but I'm in trouble with the others.
Since `n` is big, and I don't want to use my big integer library, I can't calculate `pow(2,n)` without modulo. A code snippet for the first term:

```
while (n--){
    temp = (temp << 1) % 10;
};
```

but for the second I have no idea. I also cannot `floor` them individually, since it would give '0' (2/10). Is it possible to achieve this?
(http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-16/ for the easier solution.) Of course I will look for other way if it cannot be done with this method. (for example storing digits in byte array, as in the comment in the link).

**Edit:** Thanks for the existing answers, but I look for some way to solve it mathematically. I've just came up with one idea, which can be implemented without bignum or digit-vectors, I'm gonna test if it works.

So, I have the equation above for the sum. But `2^n/10^k` can be written as `2^n/2^(log2 10^k)` which is `2^(n-k*log2 10)`. Then I take it's fractional part, and its integer part, and do modular exponentiation on the integer part: `2^(n-k*log2 10) = 2^(floor(n-k*log2 10)) * 2^(fract(n-k*log2 10))`. After the last iteration I also multiply it with the fractional modulo 10. If it won't work or if I'm wrong somewhere in the above idea, I stick to the vector solution and accept an answer.

**Edit:** Ok, it seems **doing modular exponentiation with non-integer modulo is not possible(?)** (or I haven't found anything about it). So, I'm doing the digit/vector based solution.

#### The code does NOT work fully!

It does not give the good value: (1390 instead of 1366):

```
typedef long double ldb;

ldb mod(ldb x, ldb y){             //accepts doubles
    ldb c(0);
    ldb tempx(x);
    while (tempx > y){
        tempx -= y;
        c++;
    };
    return (x - c*y);
};

int sumofdigs(unsigned short exp2){
    int s = 0;
    int nd = floor((exp2) * (log10(2.0))) + 1;
    int c = 0;
    while (true){
        ldb temp = 1.0;
        int expInt = floor(exp2 - c * log2((ldb)10.0));
        ldb expFrac = exp2 - c * log2((ldb)10.0) - expInt;
        while (expInt>0){
           temp = mod(temp * 2.0, 10.0 / pow(2.0, expFrac)); //modulo with non integer b:
                //floor(a*b) mod m = (floor(a mod (m/b)) * b) mod m, but can't code it
            expInt--;
        };
        ldb r = pow(2.0, expFrac);
        temp = (temp * r);
        temp = mod(temp,10.0);
        s += floor(temp);
        c++;
        if (c == nd) break;
    };
    return s;
};
```

Comment: that "Since `n` is big" comment got me - it's on the line break and didn't realize that's what you were after until after I had an answer.  doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you mention, you have the answer which will work as is for any number with n <= 63. So... why do you ask?

If you have to program your own everything then you need to know how to calculate a binary division and handle very large numbers. If you don't have to program everything, get a library for large integer numbers and apply the algorithm shown in the link:

```
BigNumber big_number;
big_number = 1;
big_number <<= n;
int result = 0;
while(big_number != 0) {
    result += big_number % 10;
    big_number /= 10;
}
return result;
```

Now, implementing BigNumber would be fun. From the algorithm we see that you need assignment, shift to left, not equal, modulo and division. A BigNumber class can be fully dynamic and allocate a buffer of integers to make said big number fit. It can also be written with a fixed size (as a template for example). But if you don't have the time, maybe this one will do:

https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've already have a bigint lib (boost's). I just try to solve it without any first. Since it's from http://projecteuler.net/, (I think) there must be another way to solve it using (mainly) math. :D

Comment: A month ago I've started to implement a bignum class, but after I've read it would take years to make one that works pretty well, I downloaded one... Accepted this, with a big int library it was easy to solve. Also trying to do the vector based solution. +1

Comment: I've looked into that a long time ago. In my case I just wanted the very first decimal digit of a binary number. There is just no other way than computing all the digits, which in a way is sad, but that's just the way it is...

Answer (score 2):

You could create a vector of the digits using some of the techniques mentioned in this other question ([C++ get each digit in int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615046/c-get-each-digit-in-int)) and then just iterate over that vector and add everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in JavaScript as below for finding the sum of digits of 2^1000: (Check out working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pikeshmn/pen/dzzGRa))

```js
function calculate(){
  var num = 0, totalDigits = 1,exponent =0,sum=0,i=0,temp=0, carry;  
  var arr = ['1'];

  //Logic to implement how we multiply in daily life using carry forward method
  while(exponent<1000){ //Mention the power
    carry=0;
    for(var j=arr.length-1;j>=0;j--){
      temp = arr[j]*2 + carry;
      arr[j]= temp%10;
      carry = parseInt(temp/10);
      if(carry && !j){
        arr = [carry].concat(arr); //if the last nth digit multiplication with 2 yields a carry, increase the space!
      }
    }
    exponent++;
  }
  
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum = sum+parseInt(arr[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').value = sum; //In my HTML code, I am using result textbox with id as 'result'
  //console.log(arr);
  //console.log(sum);
}
```