# Optimization of simple code for Project Euler 16

Tags: c++, debugging

I was just solving some problems at Euler when I came across a simple problem, no. 16, and I wrote a simple program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long num = pow(2,15);
    int sum=0;
    int rem,k=10;
    while(!num/10<10)
    {
        rem = num%10;
        sum+=rem;
        num=num/10;
    }
    sum+=num;
    cout<<"the sum of digits is "<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

I don’t know why but this code is taking a lot more time than expected. How to optimize it? Many of my programs take a lot more time to complete the execution than expected…

Comment: Maybe you need to compile with -O3 or something of the sort.

Comment: How I mean I dont know about -O3

Comment: On the command line, to get full optimization.

Comment: Its still taking a lot time I mean I did'nt get the output until now while commenting again

Comment: change your while condition to ((num/10)>=10)

Answer (score 7):

```
while(!num/10<10)
```

is your problem.

You are dividing !num by 10;

The test should also be < 1

try

```
while(!(num/10<1))
```

or

```
while(num/10 > 0)
```

Comment: I've made the changes and it worked good for 2 to the power 15 but its giving me incorrect results for 2 to the power 1000 Why? and thanx for the help

Comment: Couldn't we further assume that `num / 10 > 0` is equivalent to `num >= 10` which would be a tad bit faster?

Comment: @user3141305 an unsigned long long is not long enough to hold the 1001 bits required.  You should get an overflow warning from the compiler

Comment: I had this problem before also whats the maximum type I could use in C++

Comment: @AlexisWilke You're probably right and it would be a clearer solution too.

Comment: @user3141305, you may want to see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294581/calculate-floorpow2-n-10-mod-10-sum-of-digits-of-pow2-n/21298765#21298765