# matlab precision dealing with big number

Tags: matlab, precision

The question encountered me when I was trying to solve Project Euler #16.

The problem reads:

> 2<sup>15</sup> = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2<sup>1000</sup>?

I was trying to deal with it with MATLAB. Here's my code:

```
function [sum] = power_digit_sum_p16(pow)
    sum = 0;
    n = 2 ^ pow;
    M = zeros(1,301);
    for i = 301 : -1 : 0
        a = floor(n / 10 ^ i);
        M(302 - i) = a;
        sum = sum + a;
        n = n - 10 ^ i * a;
    end
end
```

(Where the 301 stands for 301 digits of 2^1000)

When I ran `pow_digit_sum_p16(1000)`, MATLAB returned 1285, which is wrong.

Then I checked the number provided by MATLAB, which is stored in matrix `M`, when I learned that something is wrong.

The last digit of 2^1000 should be 6 instead of 2 (it follows a 2-4-8-6-2-4-8-6 pattern)！  I don't understand what's going on here with MATLAB, but I guess the problem occurred because the number is too big, since my function works fine when `pow` is small.

My friend provided me with a Python solution, and it seems that python handles the big number well. Below is the code in Python:

```py
x=2**1000
ans=0
while x>0:
    ans+=(x%10)
    x=x//10
print(ans)
```

Update: thanks to OmG's answer, I changed my code a little bit:

```
function [sum] = power_digit_sum_p16(pow)
    sum = 0;
    n = 2 ^ pow;
    n = sym(n);                     % This line is new!
    M = zeros(1,301);
    for i = 301 : -1 : 0
        a = floor(n / (10 ^ i));
        M(302 - i) = a;
        sum = sum + a;
        n = n - (10 ^ i) * a;
    end
end
```

And I got what I expected. Note that the `sym` function needs the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: I assume it's related to the precision of the number that is related to the problem you've described above.

Comment: So any idea to do to increase the precision in MATLAB computation? The fact that python handles it well make me kind of "jealous".

Comment: Use the repeating pattern property, read here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two  "The 0th through 95th powers of two"

Comment: Python has arbitrary-precision integers. Matlab doesn't, unless you use symbolic computations

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the problem to compute the sum of the digits *without* an explicit calculation of `2^1000` ?  Project Euler is about cunning, not about brute force.

Comment: Hi, High Performance Mark. I got your point, yours suggestion is absolutely right. What make me wonder here is similar algorithm work in Python but not MATLAB. If Python's integer can be as precise as wanted, then I have to admit Python has some advantages here over MATLAB.

Comment: MATLAB also has an arbitrary precision number class (`vpa`). It comes with the symbolic toolbox I think.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294581/calculate-floorpow2-n-10-mod-10-sum-of-digits-of-pow2-n

Comment: Also interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006159/leading-digits-of-large-power-of-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is using symbolic tools. For example for finding the true value for the remaining for `2^1000` over `10` you can do it likes the following:

```
x = sym('2^1000');
reminder = fix(double(mod(x,10)))
```

The answer is:

```
 reminder = 
 6
```

For `100` and `1000` is `67` and `376` respectively.

Comment: Something to improve in your answer, 1.solutio--->solution(a typo) 2. x=sym(2^1000), do not make it a string.